# Python meshgrid wrong shape

Tags: python, numpy

I want to meshgrid an array of 100 elements with another of 25. But when I do so the shape becomes (25,25) instead of (100x25)

Example:

```
x = np.asarray([1,2,3,4,5,6])
y = np.asarray([1,2,3])

X,Y = np.meshgrid(x,y)

Z = np.zeros((len(x), len(y)))
```

I was expecting the shape to be (6x3), but it is (3x3) instead. Why is that so? Any ideas on how to how fix that?

Thanks

Comment: It is 6x3 in my computer

Comment: What are you checking `Z` or `X`?